# Asked to interview for different position from application

Tags: interviewing, applications, title

I applied to a company for a job as Configuration Manager. Today I received a call for an interview for an Assistant Software Engineer. Now I am very confused! How do I know which job the interview is for?

Comment: Job titles really don't mean anything - it's the job duties that are important. The only people who know the answer to this question are the company you are interviewing with. You should ask them, not us.

Comment: @DavidK i try to call the hr department but they are not picking the phone, now i am confused prepare myself for Software engineer interview or Configuration manager.

Comment: @DavidK if you can guide me that will be great help.

Comment: Your question should really be: "What should I do when I apply for 'position x', but get a call about an interview for 'position y'?

Comment: Related question: [What to do when offered interview for different/wrong job after application](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85156/what-to-do-when-offered-interview-for-different-wrong-job-after-application)

Comment: @naeem If they aren't picking up the phone, then I suggest sending an email. Unless the interview is today, a few hours of waiting won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I know which job the interview is for?

You ask.

Call and ask HR (or the recruiter if there was one) something like "Sorry. I applied for a Configuration Manager position. But the invitation I received today is for an Assistant Software Engineer. Is that the same thing in your company?"

It's quite possible that the "Assistant Software Engineer" position is used for several junior-level roles and might include the person doing configuration management. If you accepted the invitation by phone you could have clarified then. But now, just ask.

Comment: Also possible that there was a "I would like to be considered for other open positions" checkbox somewhere in the application process.

Comment: Always ask when in doubt but Joe is probably correct; or they felt your CV better reflected another role (and yes, job titles really can be meaningless at times so don't let that put you off). I applied for one job position and was interviewed for an additional two positions (in a single interview) based on the experience and skills / knowledge on my CV. Congratulations on getting the interview :) good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the company has multiple positions open. Try checking the company's website. Usually there's a section like "employment opportunities" that should have information on open positions, brief job descriptions, etc.  It may list both Configuration Manager and Assistant Software Engineer as positions.

The other possibility is that (as another answer mentioned) they are looking for an "assistant software engineer" to do "configuration management".  In which case the position is the same as what you applied for.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know which job the interview is for?

You should have queried when you got the call.

Nothing you can do now except persist in trying to contact HR.

Assistant Software engineer seems a very low level job. If it's totally different from Configuration Manager (no idea what that is). Then I'd just decline the interview. But this should have been done when you got the call. Your options now if you can't contact HR is either go to the interview, or don't go.

Comment: Configuration management includes things like tracking software deliveries and other artifacts. Hardware or CAD etc